# How to run PowerShell code from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script, that I want to run from within my C# application.

```
$adapters=(gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration ) 
Foreach ($adapter in $adapters){
Write-Host $adapter
  $adapter.settcpipnetbios(2)
}
$nics=([wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration')
Foreach($nic in $nics){
 Write-Host $adapter
$nic.enablewins($false,$false)
}
```

This is what I tried so far, using the "using System.Management.Automation;," but the script is not working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
ps.AddArgument("$adapters=(gwmi 
win32_networkadapterconfiguration )");
ps.AddArgument("Foreach($adapter in $adapters){");
ps.AddArgument(" Write - Host $adapter");
ps.AddArgument("$adapter $adapter.settcpipnetbios(2)}");
//WINS LMHOSTS lookup
ps.AddArgument("$nics = ([wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration')");
ps.AddArgument("Foreach($nic in $nics){");
ps.AddArgument(" Write - Host $adapter");
ps.AddArgument("$nic.enablewins($false,$false)}");
```

Comment: Yes, see the exception below.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Comment: "Write - Host" perhaps, and ps.Invoke

Comment: No, that did not work.

Comment: I just don't know why you are executing a powershell script from a c# app. You can use the same WMI commands inside of c#

Comment: Hey Jasin, I did that because I didn't know how to do it in C#. If you know, can you maybe convert my code to C#?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a `ps.Invoke();` at the end of your code. Or did you just leave that out of your listing?

You can find more information about the different ways to execute the PowerShell code in this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/ (Section "Script/Command Execution:" and below.)

Comment: Hey, Benjamin, the script seems to be running now, but I am getting the following exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll." Would you know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to put your whole script into an `AddScript` call? I don't think you are supposed to use `AddParameter` the way you are doing it. This would only be needed if you wanted to input a dynamically generated parameter into your script. Instead you can just prepare the whole thing with one call to `AddScript` and invoke it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but am getting the same exception.

Comment: Hi Tony, could you please post more details from the exception?

Comment: Hey Benjamin see the details as requested below.

Comment: System.Management.Automation.ParseException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParseException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
Additional information: System error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help I found a solution. To make the script work, I had to structure the code as follow.

```
 //Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP - 2=disable, 1=enable, 0=DHCP default
 //And WINS LMHOSTS lookup
 string script = @"
 $adapters=(gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration )
 Foreach($adapter in $adapters)
 {
    Write-Host $adapter
    $adapter.settcpipnetbios(2)
  }
  $nics=([wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration')
  Foreach($nic in $nics){
  Write-Host $adapter
  $nic.enablewins($false,$false)
  }
  ";

  PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
  powerShell.AddScript(script);
  powerShell.Invoke();
```

For those who don't know, this code will disable LMhosts Lookup and Disable NetBios over TCP/IP; remember to run it with administrative rights.